# How to change the background color of the tabs in the action bar?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-actionbar

How do I change the color of the tabs in the action bar of my application.

**Tabs:**

[image: android tabs]

**Current code to add the tabs:**

```
    private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
{
    ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("All");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText("Technology");
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText("Business");
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a custom theme xml file which is set under the values folder. 
For example in a theme named Example you could use the following code, if you have a drawable ready, or you could use a colour instead.

`<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>`

I'd recommend visiting [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light_dark&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=1&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=2D2D2D%2C100&secondaryColor=555555%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=303030%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=002E3E%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) as it makes styling your action bar and tabs really easy and saves you some time.

Don't forget to change the theme under your android manifest xml file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I not do this programmatically in Java?

Comment: yeah, you can. `final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` then `actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow));` replace the R.drawable.shadow with yours. You can create the a drawable xml file in the drawable folder with the colour you want.